# How can I validate my thread safety model in Python?

Tags: python, testing, thread-safety

I am working on [ddbmock project](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ddbmock). Basically, this is a server reproducing Amazon's DynamoDB API.

Even though this implementation does not involve threads directly, it is very likely to be run in multi-threaded environment and, at the moment, I know it has unpredictable "features" :) All threads will work on the same store...

The first step will be to add mutex but how can I test that I missed none and the design is actually working ? Is there any reliable way ?

Comment: Assuming you have a unit testing suite, you should add more tests that use the library in a threaded environment.

Comment: @kcbanner The problem with threading bugs is that they're not deterministic and hence almost impossible to test reliably (I know of some attempts that seem to work relatively well, but they work by hijacking context switching, are platform-specific, and none of them is for Python).

Comment: All the unit test environment I'm familiar with assume single thread execution. Running the unit test multi-threaded will not help you identify concurrency bug because of the non-deterministic nature. But it will ruin you unit test because the tests and the library are often not designed to run multi-threaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@martineau, the problem is not restricted to CPython. Anytime there is shared resources it can lead to concurrency problem.

One way is to avoid it altogether. Serialize everything and allow no concurrency. Given this is an in memory mock server this may be a reasonable restriction.

But if you do want to provide parallel access, the strategy I'd use is to stress test the system using a variety of request for a long period of time. This tend to shake out good number of race condition bugs. Otherwise I know of no reliable way to proof a program is free of concurrency bug.

Answer (score 4):

Watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zEaosS1U5qY) and you'll realize there is **no** way to do reliably what you want in CPython.
That's simply because python defers **everything** to the OS. It does not control (actively) the scheduling in any way, it just releases the GIL sometimes letting the OS do the context switch *if* and *when* it wants. This has some ugly consequences on multi-core computers.

Anyway in other languages it's also something that is really **hard** to do. Debugging concurrent programs is a hell, that's why you should avoid it as much as possible(if you want to make reliable tests).